# Python - Tried to write a vigenere cipher that doesn't ignore spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, vigenere

I tried to change my Vigenere program so that it will output the message with spaces. 
It should do this: 
translatedMessage('JPZFR DTZA NKC HFHOUC', 'cloudy', 'd') => 'HELLO FROM THE FUTURE'

```
 def translateMessage(message, key, mode):
    translated = ''
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    keyIndex = 0
    message = message.upper()
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message:
        xyz = alphabet.find(symbol.upper())
        if xyz != -1:
            if mode == 'encrypt' or 'e':
                xyz += alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1
            elif mode == 'decrypt' or 'd':
                xyz -= alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1

            xyz %= len(alphabet)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated += alphabet[xyz]
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated += alphabet[xyz].lower()

            keyIndex += 1
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else : translated += symbol #this will add space as it is

    return translated
```

Instead it gives this: 
translatedMessage('JPZFR DTZA NKC HFHOUC', 'cloudy', 'd') => 'MBOAV CWLP IOB KRWJYB'

Comment: Just a note: instead of your `alphabet` you can use [string.ascii_uppercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase)

Comment: What is the question?  Have you tried printing within the loop to see what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks mainly fine, but you can notice that you always encrypt, whatever mode you choose.

This is caused by your

```
if mode == 'encrypt' or 'e':
```

line. Because `or` has a lower [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`, this gets parsed as:

```
if (mode == 'encrypt') or 'e':
```

As `mode` is 'd', `(mode == 'encrypt')` is `False`. But as `'e'` is a non-empty string, it evaluates to `True` in boolean context.
So, `(mode == 'encrypt') or 'e'` is always `True`, whatever mode you choose.

What you need is:

```
  if mode == 'encrypt' or mode =='e':
```

Comment: `mode.lower() in ('encrypt', 'e')` may be simpler and more efficient. +1 regardless.

Comment: `{'encrypt', 'e'}` would be even better